# What tense is this sentence in 'It has been considered'

Tags: tense

'It has been ...' suggests that it is in present perfect continuous but the verb 'consider' should ends with '-ing' in perfect continuous. 
Why this is gramatically correct, or maybe it isn't?

Thanks!

Comment: It is present (*has*) perfect (*HAVE been*) passive (*BE considered*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfect contruction, the lexical (main) verb does not indicate the tense. What indicates the tense is the perfective auxiliary verb—i.e the form of *HAVE* before the past participle. So "it has been considered" is present tense.

Now what is "been" here?

The main use of the form of *BE* is to mark a *progressive aspect* and a **passive voice***. In the progressive aspect, the *BE* is followed by a present participle verb as in

> He has been running. (Active voice with progressive aspect)

In the passive voice, it's followed by a past participle, as in your example

> It has been considered wrong. (Passive voice with perfect aspect)

---

<sub>*Not always. Not all passive contructions are marked by *BE*. We also have bare passive, concealed passive, and get-passive. Those don't need a *BE* to mark them.</sub>